# How to validate lightwindow?

Tags: javascript, typo3, lightwindow

Even though its origin stickmanlabs.com seems to be down, lightwindow remains a popular javascript lightbox for various purpose. Particularly the TYPO3 community seems to like it thanks to an [extension that neatly embeds](http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/extension-manuals/wt_lightwindow/0.5.0/view/1/1/) it. However, unfortunately this extension uses an a tag attribute `params` which actually isn't an attribute. It's not valid? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a hack, but it validates lightwindow as HTML Transitional. 
Just use the hardly used `rev` [tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp) to transport the lightwindow parameters to .js.

e.g.:

```
<a href="somelink.html" rev="lightwindow_type=external,lightwindow_width=870,
lightwindow_height=650,lightwindow_show_images=2">
```

Then just edit the javascript file (in TYPO3 it's located @: typo3conf/ext/wt_lightwindow/files/js/lightwindow.js ) like this:

```
_setupWindowElements : function(link) {
    this.element = link;
    this.element.title = null ? '' : link.getAttribute('title');
    this.element.author = null ? '' : link.getAttribute('author');
    this.element.caption = null ? '' : link.getAttribute('caption');
    this.element.rel = null ? '' : link.getAttribute('rel');
    this.element.params = null ? '' : link.getAttribute('rev');
```

(should be around line 550 of the current version). Just cmd+f for params.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me if I also change the line around 1843:
from:

```
var parameterString = Form.serialize(this._getParameter('lightwindow_form', element.getAttribute('params')));
```

to:

```
var parameterString = Form.serialize(this._getParameter('lightwindow_form', element.getAttribute('rev')));
```